# why the head tag is empty in firebug page source

Tags: html, firefox, height, head

The source of page in firebug is incorrect - [its shows the head tag content after body tag](http://uploadkon.ir/uploads/a253cc906e5af17a8947ecf5a46c8f4a.jpg):

```
<head>empty</head><body>head content here...</body>
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing the **exact** html you're generating (assuming you're generating it somehow)

Comment: We'd need to see your code (generating code) and know some more about the problem. Context is always key when asking questions!

Comment: but i see and say it here,now i attention to source at two place,in firefox source and in firebug,i understood that its incorrect in firebug,not firefox,excuse me for mistake,see this pic plz:[link](http://uploadkon.ir/uploads/a253cc906e5af17a8947ecf5a46c8f4a.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

This happens when the parser sees a non-whitespace, non-markup character at the start of the file.

In a couple of recent SO questions that I've seen, this has down to the HTML page having two byte order marks (BOMs) at the start of the file. These don't show up in View Source, but they will cause the effect you see. There are other possible related reasons but a double BOM is the first thing to look for.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed my problem very quickly. Gotta love Stack Overflow.